# While using CellTree where to implement TreeViewModel (View / Presenter)

Tags: gwt, gwt-mvp

I am trying to use CellTree, i am confused about placement of class implementing  TreeViewModel,  This class will need Collection of elements required to be rendered as tree if this is view type class i need to push collection from the presenter. If its a Presenter class i can directly call the server function and get the collection.

I am finding it more near to Presenter.... please sugget

Answer (score 0):

According to [GWT docs](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html#Views),

> A key concept of MVP development is
>   that a view is defined by an
>   interface. This allows multiple view
>   implementations based on client
>   characteristics (such as mobile vs.
>   desktop)

So, looks like Presenter should know neither about data presentation widgets used in view implementation, nor about specific ViewModels and data providers used by these data presentation widgets (since data presentation widgets may be changed). ViewModels are generally coupled with particular way to implement data presentation, so I usually consider them as a part of View.

I usually create presenter methods like getObjectsList(params), which return array / list of required data, and then transform these results to ViewModel.

BTW, it would be great to hear other opinions :)